# ASP.NET MVC4: How to pass a view model and other data to the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, viewmodel

I have created a ViewModel called DashboardViewModel:

```
public class DashboardViewModel
{        
    public Hardware Hardware { get; set; }
    public Software Software { get; set; }      
}
```

I am passing the ViewModel to the view in my ActionResult.  But I need to pass other things too.  Here is my ActionResult:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

    HardwareType hwt = new HardwareType { HType = "PC" };
    IEnumerable<Hardware> Pcs = db.Hardware.Where(h => h.HardwareType.Contains(hwt));

    DashboardViewModel dvm = new DashboardViewModel();   

    return View(dvm);
}
```

How do I pass `Pcs` to the view if I am already passing `dvm`?  I don't even know if this is the right approach.  What I am trying to accomplish is to create navigation on the page.  So not only will I have PCs, but I'll have monitors and printers to pass to the view, as well as software.  Here is my hardware class:

```
public class Hardware
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DeviceType> Type { get; set; }
    public string AssetTagId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Manufacturer> Manufacturer { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string ServiceTagId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(75)]
    public string ProductNumber { get; set; }
    // [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string PurchaseDate { get; set; }
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string WarrantyExpiration { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string WarrantyType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Location> Location { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<HardwareType> HardwareType { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(2000)]
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public string POATag { get; set; }
}
```

What is the best approach for what I want to do (creating the navigation with various categories of hardware and software)?  I'm new to MVC and am trying to follow suggestions on what to do, but I could use a higher level approach as maybe I'm going about this all wrong.  Thanks.

Comment: Also, what would the Razor syntax be?

Comment: What is your 'HardwareType Class'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your `Pcs` in `ViewBag or ViewData` as below:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

    HardwareType hwt = new HardwareType { HType = "PC" };
    IEnumerable<Hardware> Pcs = db.Hardware.Where(h => h.HardwareType.Contains(hwt));
    ViewBag.Pcs=Pcs;//or ViewData["Pcs"]=Pcs;

    DashboardViewModel dvm = new DashboardViewModel();   

    return View(dvm);
}
```

`ViewBag` is the dynamic object. You can add anything to it. With any name e.g. yous `Pcs` can also be stored in `ViewBag` as `ViewBag.AnyNameYouLike=Pcs;`

```
**RAZOR SYNTAX:**
```

Just apply loop and you are done.

```
@foreach(var pc in ViewBag.Pcs)
{
  @pc.Id;//Will give you id

}
```

You can loop through all properties like this

Comment: I tried this approach and it told me that it didn't know what ViewBag.Pcs was.

Comment: It said it didn't exist in the current context, even though I had `@model CIT.ViewModels.DashbaordViewModel` in my view.

Comment: This is the message the compiler gives me: `Unable to create a constant value of type 'CIT.Models.HardwareType'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.`

Answer (score 0):

Create a top level view-model - like you have `DashboardViewModel` - and add all the necessary models as Properties.

It would be good if you created view-models for each business model required in that top level view-model.

Auto-map the business objects to the new view-models - see [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) for one example. That way you are only passing the information the view actually requires.